# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Message':

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error using the object spread operator:

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Message':...`

`returnMessage` has been assigned a type though so I can't work out what I should do?

My code:

```
  dispatchMessages = (message: Message): void => {
    this.setState({ messageFromDashboard: message });
    const messageCopyFromState: Message = { ...this.state.messageFromDashboard };
    let returnMessage: Message;
    setTimeout(() => {
      returnMessage = this.createMessageFromServer(messageCopyFromState);
      this.setState({ messageToDashboard: returnMessage });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you initially assigning the state of `messageFromDashboard` in your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your component state? You can try to define it like this:

```
type State = {
  messageFromDashboard: Message
  // your other state properties
}

type Props = any;

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-native if you want to use a property of state with it's type then first you have to declare state with each of it's properties that you gonna use check example below :

```js
interface IState {
  message: Message;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  
  constructor(props : any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: new Message()
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return <span>{`${this.props.superhero} health is: ${this.state.health}`}</span>
  }
}
```